# Angular Reactive Forms With ASP.NET

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular-reactive-forms

Is there a way to access reactive forms data sent to Web API when i don't have a predefined model class in .Net?

Basically the form is generated dynamically based on a JSON object so it can be like

```
{
 firstName:"Ankit",
amount:888
}
```

or

```
{
firstName:"Ankit",
lastName:"xyz"
}
```

so in that sense i don't have model class predefined

Comment: Yes, you can do that. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @yurzui I have received the json object sent from the reactive form as a Dictionary of strings . But this doesn't serve the purpose for datatype-specific validations such as DateTime. As we don't know which field in the reactive form will be a Date, we don't know which  value in the dictionary should be parsed

Comment: I think you should use such json where you define type of control i.e. text, date, checkbox. And then you can generate form based on this information Here is a good article to start https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms

Comment: my metaData(JSON) contains info abt the input type , so i am generating the form based on that. But when the form is filled and sent there is only key and value in submitted form's JSON. So should i use the same meta data and keeping it side by side with form data and compare the value to find it is of which dataType?

Comment: Here is my example of building such forms https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-typescript-systemjs/tree/lection/src/reactive-driven-forms. I synchronize meta data with form value